# Excel X-Y-Chart multicolored line

Tags: excel, charts, null

I logged the battery stats of my robotic mower like this:
[image]

Out of this data I'd like a X-Y-chart like this:
[image: desired chart]

If I'd only need one color this would be a simple X-Y-chart out of the first two columns. Now I want to highlight charging times.

I found no direct way to draw the chart from the above data thus I **created a helper table**, which creates **two interweaved data lines**. This table is **filled with formulas** out of the source table. When the formula evaluates to "", the **line in chart drops to zero**. Thus I **removed the formula** for the visually empty cells manually.

[image: helper table]

I've got two questions:

1. Is it possible to **draw the chart directly** from the source data?
2. If using the helper table: how to **not have the line drop to 0** if the formula results in ""?

This my [current Excel sheet](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4jnj5paewybu6ru/GardenaMowerBattery.xlsx/file).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to draw the chart directly from the source data?

imho : no.

> If using the helper table how to not have the line drop to 0 if the formula results in ""?

```
=IF(<originalFormula>="",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address")),-1,0)
```

(take the previous row value)

Comment: The original line is continuous.
I only began cutting it into two lines to have it colored.
If I made both new lines continuous again, one would overlap the other.

I attached my Excel sheet for you to experiment.

Comment: I had look into the shared files..  Undestanding that ".. I want to highlight charging times." is your target. From what I can see, you had done it the way it should and it was done properly too ( the highlight part.. by plotting 2 lines on another..). | btw.. u asked : "using the helper table how to not have the line drop to 0.. " putting "" IS a solution ( I use `=ERROR.TYPE(1)` )

Comment: i have a question.. the 'formula' in ".. how to not have the line drop to 0 if the formula results in "" .. " refers to formula in helper column or the original Level/Charging column ?

Comment: I was referring to the helper table. Autofill the the empty cells with the formula from the filled cells. Cell values remain empty but chart line drops to 0.